# Elasticsearch prefix suggestion?

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

How is it possible to get term suggestions by prefix, I have the **name** field.

I have three records:

*sitting in the mid of the place*

*making the minimum job done*

*canal mib gone*

I want to be able to get the word **minimum** as a suggested term when I type **min** but I do get **mid** and **mib** which are in the other documents.

This is my query:

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "min",
    "simple_phrase": {
      "term": {
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "field": "Name.raw",
        "min_word_length": 2,
        "prefix_length": 1,
        "suggest_mode": "always"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**MAPPING**:

```
{
  "Name": {
    "type": "text",
    "index": "not_analyzed",
    "include_in_all": true,
    "fields": {
      "raw": {
        "type": "text",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "include_in_all": false
      },
      "trigram": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "trigram_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**RESULT**

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "suggest": {
    "simple_phrase": [
      {
        "text": "min",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 3,
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "mib",
            "score": 0.6666666,
            "freq": 79
          },
          {
            "text": "mid",
            "score": 0.6666666,
            "freq": 59
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says in documentation:

> The term suggester suggests terms based on edit distance. The provided suggest text is analyzed before terms are suggested. The suggested terms are provided per analyzed suggest text token. The term suggester doesn’t take the query into account that is part of request.

So, term suggestor just "edit" your text. So you can try something like this, to see `minimum` as suggested result:

```
{
  "suggest": {
    "text" : "minimam",
    "simple_phrase" : {
      "term" : {
        "analyzer" : "standard",
        "field" :  "Name.raw",
        "min_word_length" : 1,
        "suggest_mode" : "always"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I think, that for your purpose it is better to use [completion suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vadim. I thought about using the completion suggester but it returns whole documents instead of tokens or keywords. So when i type min it returns the whole " making the minimum job done " which is not what i need

Comment: Then you can use this analyzer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/analysis-word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html

And use  completion suggester whit it.